# What's the best way to deal with English pluralisation in a rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pluralize

I generally do something like this, but if feels nasty and not very dry:

```
-if minutes == 1
  added #{minutes} minute ago
-else
  added #{minutes} minutes ago
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-pluralize

```
"added #{ pluralize(minutes, "minute") } ago"
```

There is an optional third argument that you can add if the plural version is non-standard and rails can't figure it out.  For example (from the docs):

```
pluralize(3, 'person', 'users')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<%= pluralize(minutes, "minute") %> if you're in a view.
```